# how should I parse a 5gb WARC file using C++?

Tags: c++, xml, winapi, warc

The WARC files are from the Common Crawl. A sample:

```
WARC-Type: response
WARC-Date: 2018-12-09T20:26:32Z
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:5e578aa4-4ec1-4b48-a3ff-cc0a154660f8>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta http-equiv="Content
```

Environment:
I am using C++ on VS 2019 in Windows. I prefer not to use special libraries. I looked at mapping the file in memory but someone said it is not as fast when you are simply parsing the file sequentially. Because I am in windows, I get a nice GUI but I also get all the Unicode mess.

Desired output of the parse:
I have an output file where I want to save most of the text and some of the tags. I will be discarding most of the input. Some warc tags signal to the parser that it can skip ahead say 500 characters. For example, any "WARC-Type" other than "WARC-Type: response" can skip ahead a known amount.

What I have tried:
reading the file into a heap buffer and then slicing the buffer using a sliding window. skip/save based on content of window. Able to catch a tag that spans buffers. Eventually I will use things like regex and string::find to match tags and text.

The big problem: Unicode. The file is UTF-8 with all kinds of interesting characters as you can imagine. I use MultiByteToWideChar. If I only convert the window, I don't use as much memory but I run into problems with text lining up. 15 characters of UTF-8 does not produce 15 characters of ANSI. Depending on my multibtyetowidechar flags, size, etc. I get text skipped, decode errors, etc. If I convert the entire buffer and then slice into a window, I am using twice as much memory. not that big of a deal but it seems inefficient.

```
BOOL pageActive = FALSE;
BOOL xml = FALSE;
#define MAXBUFFERSIZE 1024
#define MAXTAGSIZE 64
DWORD windowStart = 0; DWORD windowEnd = 15; DWORD windowSize = 15;
DWORD bufferSize = MAXBUFFERSIZE;
_int64 fileRemaining;

HANDLE hFile;
DWORD  dwBytesRead = 0;
LARGE_INTEGER dwPosition;
TCHAR* buffer;

hFile = CreateFile(
        inputFilePath,         // file to open
        GENERIC_READ,          // open for reading
        FILE_SHARE_READ,       // share for reading
        NULL,                  // default security
        OPEN_EXISTING,         // existing file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // normal file    | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
        NULL);                 // no attr. template

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DisplayErrorBox((LPWSTR)L"CreateFile");
        return 0;
    }

LARGE_INTEGER size;
GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size);

_int64 fileSize = (__int64)size.QuadPart;

if(fileSize > MAXBUFFERSIZE){buffer = new TCHAR[MAXBUFFERSIZE];}
else{buffer = new TCHAR[fileSize];}

fileRemaining = fileSize;

while (fileRemaining)                                       // outer loop
{

if (bufferSize > fileRemaining)
     bufferSize = fileRemaining;

if (FALSE == ReadFile(hFile, buffer, bufferSize -1, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    {
     sendToReportWindow(L"file read failed\n");
     CloseHandle(hFile);
     return 0;
     }

fileRemaining -= bufferSize;

while (windowEnd < bufferSize)              //inner loop. while unused data remains in buffer   
    {
    windowSize = windowEnd - windowStart;
    wstring str;

    for (int i = windowStart; i <= windowEnd; i++) {
      str.append(&buffer[i]);
      }
    str[windowEnd] = '\0';

    TCHAR converted[MAXTAGSIZE] = { 0 };
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, (LPCCH)str.c_str(), -1, converted, MAXTAGSIZE);
    sendToReportWindow(L"windowStart:%d windowEnd:%d converted:%s\n", windowStart, windowEnd, converted);

    // skip these sections and continue to build the window unless there are sufficient characters in the window to make it worth checking its content.

    // to do: WARC page state (use regex and string::find)
    // allow skipping ~500 chars in some cases

    // to do: XML tags/text
    // keep track of tags that span multiple buffers

    windowStart = windowEnd;
    windowEnd++;
    }    // inner loop

delete [] buffer;
}    // outer loop
```

Comment: You definitely don't want to load an entire 5GB file into memory at one time. A sliding window, reading the file in chunks with a small memory buffer, or using file-mapped views, is a good idea. If you find that a given tag is not contained completely within the current window, expand the window until the tag is fully within the window, or use a separate buffer to collect pieces of the tag until you have the complete tag. Then (extract and) convert the tag as needed, and shrink the window if needed. Don't convert the window itself, convert only complete data you pull out using the window.

Comment: Look up SAX parsing.  There's often no need to construct a complete Document Object Model if you're just ripping data out.  With SAX methods, you just create a state machine that responds to XML tag "events".  Usually you don't need any clever buffering to do this.  The parser buffers stuff internally, so you just feed it data and it runs your state machine.  Check out Libxml2 or MSXML, which both provide SAX methods.

Comment: Even better if you have a SAX parser that supports data pushing.  Then you just read a chunk, push it into the parser, let it fire any events it can from that chunk, and repeat.

Comment: Gzip compression is part of the WARC standard: WARC files are compressed [record by record](https://iipc.github.io/warc-specifications/specifications/warc-format/warc-1.1/#record-at-time-compression) which allows to wind forwards to the next record by consuming the current gzip stream without processing the actual content.